# How can I delete a table record comparing datetime to current time in view

Tags: python, django

I need to delete a table record whenever tables record's **timestamp** or **datetime** matches **current datetime** in db. Problem is I cant get datetime values on console without using **datetimes** method if i use it I can't filter it .

here is my code

```
def query(request):
    xx = datetime.datetime.now()

    if dulesdb.objects.all():
        zzz = dulesdb.objects.datetimes('request_time','second')
        yyy = dulesdb.objects.filter(zzz > datetime.datetime.now())
        print yyy.delete() # some trick this way 
    return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to delete records having `request_time` greater than the current datetime.

To achieve this, you can filter your queryset to only get the corresponding records:

```
def query(request):
    dulesdb.objects.filter(request_time__gt=datetime.datetime.now()).delete()

    return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

This queryset will return you all records having their `request_time` attribute greater than the current time. You can then directly delete those records (with the `delete()` method).

---

You can replace the `__gt` suffix according to your needs (`__gte`: greater than or equal to, `__lt`: less than, etc.)

You'll find more info about field lookups in the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)